# Why is the Inverse Fourier Transform used for periodic signals?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In the book "Signals and Systems" by Alan V. Oppenheim, it proves that the Inverse Fourier Transform

> $$x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(jw)e^{jwt}dw,$$

is the derived from Fourier Series when $T\rightarrow \infty$. However, for some reason, the Inverse Fourier Transform is used for periodic signals. Why? Since $T\rightarrow \infty$ is for aperiodic signals.

Comment: more context is needed here; how in particular is the inverse fourier transform used on periodic signals?  one can recover the fourier series from the fourier integral by renormalizing, so that's a possibility

Comment: @user3716267 I found in some exercises the usage of (Inverse) Fourier Transform on periodic signals, there's even a subchapter "The Fourier Transform for Periodic Signals" but how come it's possible since the condition to apply these two operations is when the period tends to infinity? Period does not tends to infinity for periodic signals.

Comment: Can you reproduce any of those usages in your question?